# Creating a user defined class in java just like Integer/String class

Tags: java, generics, scope

I have a very basic doubt. Is it possible to create a class in which objects can be created using '=' operator (just like Integer/String class) rather than using "new CustomClass()".

Consider a class named CustomClass. I need to define my class just a way that it works just like Integer/String class in terms of the syntax for create objects.

Eg. In order to create Integer object we write, Integer pInt = 10 or String pStr = "testWorld";
LikeWise, I want objects of my custom class "CustomClass" to be created using simple syntax like CustomClass custObj = 45;

Comment: I think, you have worked with C++ before. C++ supports operator overloading, but unfortunately java does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Java doesn't provide a way for that. Even `String` is a special case in Java, given some extra syntax to make things easier. As for `Integer x = 10;`, that's just autoboxing although it doesn't require the `new` syntax either.

You'll have to make do with constructors and factory methods.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that's not possible. Java contains a few special cases of syntactic sugar that lets you create objects easily, but you cannot define your own. These are built into the language. This is related to that Java doesn't support overloading operators like some other languages like C++ or Scala.

Btw, another example is initializing arrays:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
```